# C#/Fortran: Unable to find an entry point

Tags: c#, interop, fortran

Keep getting the following error when trying to call a subroutine stored in a Fortran DLL from a C# console application:  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in name.exe Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'Fortran_Subroutine' in DLL 'Fortran.dll'"  Nearly all of the posts related to this error message pertain to C#/C++.  The Fortran project has a post-build event that copies the DLL over to the C# project (CSharp_proj\bin\debug).

The Fortran code uses two calls to !DEC$, do they look OK?:

```
C
  MODULE MF_DLL
C
  CONTAINS
C
  SUBROUTINE MFNWT_INIT()
C      
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: MFNWT_INIT
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE, ALIAS: "MFNWT_INIT"
C
  USE GLOBAL
  ...(do stuff)

  RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE MFNWT_INIT
```

The C# code that calls the fortran, does the DLLImport call look OK?:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class CustomMODSIM
{
    public static Model myModel = new Model();
    private static SortedList myStreamNodes;

    public static void Main(string[] CmdArgs)
    {
        string FileName = CmdArgs[0];
        myModel.Init += OnInitialize;
        ...(do more stuff)...

        //Function call that will invoke "OnInitialize" below
        myProgram.RunSolver(myModel);
    }

    private static void OnInitialize()
    {
        //call Fortran function
        MFNWT_INIT();

        //Initialize list of stream nodes
        myStreamNodes = new SortedList();
        Node m_Node = myModel.FindNode("NonStorage1");
        ...(do more stuff)
    }

    //Fortran DLL interface
    [DllImport("MF_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void MFNWT_INIT();
}
```

Comment: *"Unable to find an entry point named 'Fortran_Subroutine' in DLL 'Fortran.dll'"* Hard to believe it says that. Surely it says "Unable to find an entry point named 'MFNWT_INIT'..."?

Comment: I've been trying so many different combinations of things that I simply used generic names in my example error message.  As you point out, the error message for the particular code I added to the post was, "Unable to find an entry point named 'MFNWT_INIT' in DLL MF_DLL.dll'"

Comment: It would help if you could post the results of `dumpbin /exports MF_DLL.dll`.

Comment: I wish I could add a screen shot here, I'm not a very experienced programmer:  " 1 0 008c2fca MF_DLL_mp_mfnwt_init=_MF_DLL_mp_mpmfnwt_init" and " 2 1 008C2FCA _MF_DLL_mp_mfnwt_init@0 = _MF_DLL_mp_mfnwt_init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second compiler directive (the second !DEC$ line) is incorrect - it is missing the `:: MFNWT_INIT` part that designates which Fortran thing has the nominated attributes (DECORATE and ALIAS).  I would expect the compiler to issue a warning about the syntax problem.

For what its worth (assuming you are using a version of ifort >= 11 or so and not one of its ancestors): given you want to use the C calling convention, you are better off getting rid of that second directive completely, and just using the suffix `BIND(C,NAME="MFNWT_INIT")` on the SUBROUTINE statement.

Comment: I think it defaults to an underscore at the end of the symbol without any BIND modifiers or changes to the compiler options.

Comment: I bailed on the second !DEC$ line of code and modified the Fortran subroutine to now look like: "SUBROUTINE MFNWT_INIT() BIND(C,NAME="MFNWT_INIT")"   That did it!

Comment: I should also add for other that may find this post helpful, that I changed a C# line of code to: [DllImport("MF_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention. **StdCall**)]

Comment: Do not use StdCall with BIND(C).  BIND(C) *specifies* C calling convention - i.e. what C# calls Cdecl.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the DLL is exporting the function with a decorated name. Find out what that name is and use it on the C# side.

```
[DllImport("MF_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint="DecoratedNameGoesHere")]
public static extern void MFNWT_INIT();
```

To find the exported name use a tool like dumpbin or Dependency Walker.

Are you quite sure that your DLL uses the cdecl calling convention?

Comment: It'll most likely be `MFNWT_INIT_` or `_MFNWT_INIT` using most default compiler options.

Comment: @six Yep. The point is to show asker how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm merely pointing out the odd trailing `_` used by many Fortran compilers. I'll delete this if it misses your point.

Answer (score 0):

In the IVF Help, have a look at Building Applications/Programming with Mixed Languages/Adjusting calling conventions in Mixed Languages/Attributes properties and calling conventions.  That is where it is on Version 11.  It may have moved in the version you are using. The confusing bit in the help is whether the exported symbol is upper or lowercase.  It is only slightly different from the one written for the old MS Fortran 77 compiler (circa 1986).  If you are unsure the exported symbols, use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what they are.

1) If you are not using an alias, then it should look like this on the Fortran side

```
MODULE MF_DLL
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE MFNWT_INIT()
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL, DLLEXPORT :: MFNWT_INIT
```

If STDCALL is used, there will be two exported symbols:  MF_DLL_mp_MFNWT_INIT and _MF_DLL_mp_MFNWT_INIT@0.  If STDCALL is not specified, it defaults to C.  In that case you  will only MF_DLL_mp_MFNWT_INIT.  The number after the @ sign is the number of bytes on the stack that the routine needs to remove before returning to the caller.  You will not get this in C decl because it is the responsibility of the caller.

2) On the C# side using stdcall

```
[DllImport("MF_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall,
EntryPoint="_MF_DLL_mp_MFNWT_INIT@0")]
public static extern void MFNWT_INIT();
```

3) On the C# side using Cdecl

```
[DllImport("MF_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
EntryPoint="MF_DLL_mp_MFNWT_INIT")]
public static extern void MFNWT_INIT();
```

The difference is that in C, it does not need to know the number of parameters whereas in stdcall it does.  This affects the stacking/unstacking of parameters.  If this goes wrong, it will make the call, run the Fortran routine and then crash on exit.  In your case, it doesn't really matter because there are no parameters but it is nice to get it right.

4) If an alias is used, the name changes but not the calling convention.  In your case, you should have specified

```
!                                             ,-- This is the name in DLL export
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE, ALIAS: "MFNWT_INIT"::MFNWT_INIT
```

With C decl, you will get MFNWT_INIT.
With STDCALL, you will get MFNWT_INIT and _MFNWT_INIT@0
On the C# side the entry point is not needed when C Decl is used.  It is only needed when STDCALL is used.

5) If the routine is used in both Fortran and C# then it would be better to stick to stdcall.